# MySqlDataAdapter Fill dando erro

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-select

Ao utilizar conexão com banco de dados no C#, vi muitas formas de se fazer.

Consigo fazer a inserção de dados no banco de dados muito tranquilo, porém a seleção de dados está me deixando de cabelos brancos. Abaixo o código e logo explicarei o erro.

```
public void AtualizarGrid()
{
    grdclientes.DataSource = "";
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mConn = new MySqlConnection())
        {
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            conn_string.Server = "localhost";
            conn_string.UserID = "root";
            conn_string.Password = "guijermo10";
            conn_string.Database = "cadastro";
            conn_string.Port = 3306;

            mConn.ConnectionString = conn_string.ToString();
            mConn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cCommand = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cCommand.Connection = mConn;
                cCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cadastro.clientes";

                MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cCommand);
                DataTable dtRetorno = new DataTable();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dtRetorno);
                grdclientes.DataSource = dtRetorno;
            }
            mConn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

O meu problema é o `sqlAdapter.Fill`. Ele funciona as vezes e as vezes da erro de referência:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma
>   instância de um objeto.

E eu já fiz debug e não consegui resolver o problema, sei que o erro se dá com a perda de referência do datatable, porém não sei como resolver.

Comment: Estranho, se funciona algumas vezes, me parece erro no MySql. Qual provider você está usando? Está utilizando a última versão do mesmo?

Comment: Provider é o conector?? porque se for uso o 6.8.3 acho que a ultima versão é o 6.9.9

Comment: Isso. Tenta atualizar ou procurar por algum bug no site ou github do conector. Seu código parece normal, até porque funciona as vezes.

Comment: Ok Murilo, irei atualizar o conector e ver se muda, porque eu tentei de toda forma entender porque eu consigo fazer 2 a 5 inserções depois da esse erro de referência nula..

Comment: Olá Lorena, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) e veja se os exemplos lhe ajudam

Comment: Pessoal agradeço a ajuda de todos que tiraram um tempinho para me ajudar, e realmente o problema estava no mysql, atualizei tudo que poderia e não consegui resolver, então preferi mudar para o sql server e agora está funcionando certinho. Muito obrigada mesmo